# Help with finding the vectors $\vec{a_1}$ and $\vec{a_2}$

Tags: linear-algebra, vectors

So I have the following problem:

[image]

So I'm thinking this:

$\vec{a}=2\vec{e_1}+\vec{e_2}+\vec{e_3}=\begin{bmatrix}2\\1\\1\end{bmatrix}$

$\vec{b}=3\vec{e_1}+2\vec{e_2}+5\vec{e_3}=\begin{bmatrix}3\\2\\5\end{bmatrix}$

If we have a vector $\vec{a_1}$ then we must have that $\vec{a_1}=d\vec{b}=d\begin{bmatrix}3\\2\\5\end{bmatrix}$

For the vector $\vec{a_2}=\begin{bmatrix}x\\y\\z\end{bmatrix}$ we must have that

$\vec{a_2}\bullet\vec{b}=\begin{bmatrix}x\\y\\z\end{bmatrix}\bullet\begin{bmatrix}3\\2\\5\end{bmatrix}=0$

$\vec{a_2}\bullet\vec{b}=3x+2y+5z=0$

From this I get that:

$\vec{a_1}+\vec{a_2}=d\begin{bmatrix}3\\2\\5\end{bmatrix}+\begin{bmatrix}\frac{-2y-5z}{3}\\\frac{-3x-5z}{2}\\\frac{-3x-2y}{5}\end{bmatrix} =\begin{bmatrix}2\\1\\1\end{bmatrix}$

So I get three equations with 4 unknowns, that I'm not able to solve. I'm really stuck. Is there another way to solve this problem, or I'm I missing something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have $3x+2y+5z = 0\Rightarrow y = -\frac{3x+5z}{2}$

Substitute only one variable (here $y$ in terms of $x$ and $z$), this will reduce the no. of variables by $1$.

The mistake you've done is you've substituted $x$ in terms of $y,z$, $y$ in terms of $z,x$ and $z$ in terms of $x,y$, so the no. of variables to be determined remain same.

Now,

$$\begin{align}&3d+x = 2 \cdots (\text{eq. }1)   
\\&2d- \frac{3x+5z}{2}=1\cdots (\text{eq. }2) 
\\&5d+z = 1 \cdots (\text{eq. }3)\end{align}$$

Perform $3\times(\text{eq. }1)+2\times(\text{eq. }2)+5\times(\text{eq. }3)$ to get $d$. Then you can find $x,z$ and finally $y$

Comment: I have tried what you told me know, and I get that $d=\frac{13}{38}$, $x=\frac{37}{38}$ and $z=\frac{-27}{38}$. From these values I find out that $y=\frac{6}{19}$. Does this sound right @Ak. ?

Comment: Thank you for helping me by the way! Really appreciate it!

Comment: By the way, I noticed now that when I plug the values for x, y and z in the equation $\vec{a_2}\bullet\vec{b}=3x+2y+5z=0$, I don't get zero. Have I done something wrong?

Comment: You do get zero.$$3x+2y+5z=\frac{1}{38}(111+24-135)=0$$

Comment: Hmm, then my values for $d, x, y$ and $z$ must be wrong then. I will check again if I have done something wrong

Comment: The values are correct. Also you can check that $$d\begin{bmatrix}3\\2\\5\end{bmatrix}+\begin{bmatrix}x\\y\\z\end{bmatrix}=\frac{13}{38}\begin{bmatrix}3\\2\\5\end{bmatrix}+\frac{1}{38}\begin{bmatrix}37\\12\\-27\end{bmatrix} = \frac1{38}\begin{bmatrix}39+37\\26+12\\65-27\end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}2\\1\\1\end{bmatrix}=\vec{a}$$

Comment: Thank you so much again! I must have been mixing some numbers, because now I got zero! Thank you for your time and patience!

Comment: You're welcome! =)

Answer (score 1):

Alternate solution:

The vector $\vec b_1=\frac1{|\vec b|}\vec b$ is a unit vector parallel to $\vec b$ (and pointing in the same direction). The scalar product $\vec a\cdot\vec b_1$ tells you the length of $\vec a_1$ (it will be negative if $\vec a_1$ and $\vec b$ point in opposite directions).

Now just multiply this with $\vec b_1$ again to get $\vec a_1$:
$$
\vec a_1=\left(\vec a\cdot\vec b_1\right)\vec b_1=
$$
Finally, we get $\vec a_2=\vec a-\vec a_1$.

Comment: Thank you for your explanation!